# Does \bmdefine redefine commands without giving a warning?

Tags: bm

Just curious; does `\bmdefine` redefine commands without giving a warning? I tried compiling

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}

\bmdefine{\Omega}{O}

\begin{document}

$\Omega$

\end{document}
```

`\Omega` got redefined to print a bold math italic "O", and I didn't see any warnings in my .log file. I have bm 2017/01/16 v1.2c.

Comment: yes, it does......

Comment: Interesting hidden feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it does, if it checked there would be two commands `\newbmcommand` and `\renewbmcommand`  but (like `\declarecolor`) the `declare` here is a hint that no checking is done (in the interests of saving space and time of the machines of the day, mostly)